# Azure Devops Server: Can't get ADS search (Code, Wiki, Work Item) to work from disaster recovery site ADS web portal

Tags: search, configure, azure-devops-server-2020

[This is the only doc I can find for installing Search on ADS app server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/install-configure-search?view=azure-devops-2020). Alas, it is ambiguous and, I fear, is missing some info I need to get ADS search (Code, Wiki, Work Item) to work from my disaster recovery site ADS App Server.

Here is the setup. The WSFC and AOAG are configured and are working as expected. Note that APP01 and APP02 are not in a WSFC.

[image]

Using the ADS Admin Console on APP01, I successfully installed and configured Code, Wiki, and Work Item Search. With DB01 as the AOAG primary, when I search from the APP01 ADS web portal, results come back as expected:

[image]

Now, I want to be able to do the same search from APP02. My first try was to use the ADS Admin Console on APP02 to configure Search the same way I did on APP01. Search installed ok, but when I search from the APP02 ADS web portal, I get an error:

[image]

I went back and re-read the doc that I referenced above and came to the conclusion that I instead should have copied the contents of APP01 `{drive}:\Program Files\Azure DevOps Server 2020\Search\zip` to APP02 and followed the instructions in the readme.txt file. So, I uninstalled search from APP01 and APP02, reinstalled it on APP01, and then copied the contents of APP01 `{drive}:\Program Files\Azure DevOps Server 2020\Search\zip` to APP02 and followed the instructions in the readme.txt file, i.e., I ran `Configure-TFSSeach.ps1` on APP02. Search seemed to install ok - all good messages from the .ps1, no errors. But, when I ran the search from the APP02 ADS web portal, Same error as before.

How do I get search to work from the APP02 ADS Web Portal?

Comment: I don't think installing search on the Application Tier is only really supported for single server setups. In a multi-server setup, you install Search on its own server.

Comment: You'd install Search on a separate server and then point each Application Tier to it during the install process of each server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/install-configure-search?view=azure-devops#install-or-update-search-on-a-separate-server

Comment: Microsoft doesn't support setting up ES in cluster mode. There are no docs and multiple closed support tickets pointing out that you'll need to figure that out yourself with support from Elastic, but they (MS) don't support it.

Comment: Or you install Search with server A and then point server B to the search server on server A upon installation. Do not install more than one instance of Search.

Comment: on APP01 (from which search works), TFS Admin Console, Search section, the Search URL is http://localhost:9200. On APP02, TFS Admin console, I selected "Use an existing Search Service" and entered a `Search Service URL` == http://app01:9200, and also tried `Search Service URL` == http://app01. Both failed  to configure. Where do I get the APP01 `Search Service URL` that I need to enter into APP02 TFS Admin Console?

Comment: You may need to tweak the `elasticsearch.yml` (in `C:\Program Files\Azure DevOps Server 2020\Search\ES\elasticsearchv6.2\config`) to bind to the external IP address and open up the windows firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this scenario isn't well documented on Microsoft's side. They don't explain how to configure elastic search to scale across multiple nodes and Microsoft support closes every ticket out there on the devcommunity with the notice: "Not a supported scenario, reach out to Elastic for guidance".

The scenario that is supported it to install Elastic Search on the Application Tier for a Single Tier installation of Azure DevOps Server. That's basically what happens when you select to install Search as part of you application tier.

For security, Elastic Search is bound to the local loopback IP and no firewall ports are opened up on the first server (A), so when you install a second application tier (B), there is no way to point that at the instance of Elastic Search on A.

So, in your scenario, where you already know you need to scale, the process would be as follows:

- Install Azure DevOps on Server A do not install search.
- Manually install Search on Server A (as if it's a stand-alone installation)
- Ensure the firewall is opened to receive traffic from Server B later.
- [Configure IPSec to encrypt the traffic between Server A and Server B.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/install-configure-search?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops#secure-search)
- Install Azure DevOps on Server B, point it to the elastic Search instance on Server A during installation.

Or completely ignore Search during installation:

- Install Azure DevOps Server A. Do not configure Search.
- Install Azure DevOps Server B. Do not configure Search.
- Install Search from the zip folder on either A or B, make sure you bind it to a networked IP address.
- Open up the firewall for the required port.
- [Configure IPSec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/install-configure-search?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops#secure-search)
- [If needed change the `network.host` value in `C:\Program Files\Azure DevOps Server 2019\Search\ES\elasticsearchv6.2\config\elasticsearch.yml` to bind to a non-local IP address.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#network-interface-values)
- Configure Search on DevOps Server A to point at the instance of elastic Search.
- Configure Search on DevOps Server A to point at the instance of elastic Search.

If you already have Elastic Search installed on either Server A or Server B you can go into the Azure DevOps Admin console and remove the Search feature from the server (won't actually uninstall Elastic Search, will just remove the configuration):

[image]

Then change the network binding:

[image]

Then restart the Elastic Search service:

[image]

**Make sure you point to the Fully Qualified Domain Name of the server running ElasticSearch**, or its IP address. If you only enter the host name, the installation wizard will revert your settings back to `localhost` for some obscure reason.

[image]

See also:

- [Network configuration of Elastic Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#network-interface-values)
- [Secure Azure DevOps Search when binding to a non-local IP address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/install-configure-search?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops#secure-search)
- [Patch Elastic Search for log4j log4shell vulnerability](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-patch-for-log4j-vulnerability/)

Comment: Be sure to patch ElasticSearch after installation: https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-patch-for-log4j-vulnerability/